# How to use strategy pattern with custom sorting strategies?

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I would like to know if the approach that I am using is the best or not for this situation.

I'm developing a REST API and I have an endpoint which has to return a list of person objects. Let's say that person class has age (int), hair and vegan (both booleans), for example.

That endpoint should return persons sorted by age (younger first), if they have the same age, then those who have hair, and then those who are vegan.

The sorting strategies can be changed, as they are read from configuration file. So the endpoint could return first those who are vegan, then those who have hair and then by age.

As I see there are different strategies to be applied, I thought that the best approach would be to use strategy pattern (I also considered decorator but as the strategy can be changed I don't know how to apply it). I created an interface which returns a comparator, and then I have the strategies implementation that can be applied (hair, age and vegan), which return a comparator. I read the strategies from a configuration file and I save them into a string array.

As of this moment, there are only three strategies I use

`array.stream.sorted(strategy[0].compare().thenComparing(strategy[1].compare()).thencomparing...)`

but I see an obvious problem, that this is not scalable, because if I add one more then strategy it would not be processed.

So I have two questions here:

Is strategy pattern the best design pattern for this situation of sorting?

How could I proceed to make the strategies array that are applied more generic?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new comparator class:

```
public abstract class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
}
```

Add every type of possible comparators:

```
public class AgeComparator extends PersonComparator {
// implement comparing logic
}
public class VeganComparator extends PersonComparator {
// implement comparing logic
}
```

add a new service to obtain the comparator for encapsulation :

```
public class PersonService {

  public Comparator<Person> getComparator() {
    // obtain from configuration the list of comparators
    List<PersonComparator> comparators = //..
    Comparator<Person> comparator = comparators.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < comparators.size(); i++) {
        comparator = comparator.thenComparing(comparators.get(i));
    }
    return comparator;
  }
}
```

In this way, you can obtain the list of comparators from external configuration.
Example using jackson:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
            property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AgeComparator.class, name = "age"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = VeganComparator.class, name = "vegan")
    })
    public abstract class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

        private String type;

        //getters and setters
    }
```

and the configuration would be :

```
[
  {
    "type": "age"
  },
  {
    "type": "vegan"
  }
]
```